# What is taking time in Spark application in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a Spark application which is using Gradient Boosting Trees on a sparse matrix in libsvm format.

```html
val model = GradientBoostedTrees.train(trainingData, boostingStrategy)
```

here the trainingData is a RDD[LabeledPoint]. The size of that on hadoop is around 37 MB.

Also see the two images attached
[image: Start]
[image: After some time]

First one is from when it started. And then I took the After Some time screen shot.

If you look at the individual tasks - you will see milliseconds and seconds. If I add them up they will give me a handful of minutes. However my application is running for 1.5 hrs at the point I took the second screen shot.

So the questions I have are

1. How do I know where 90% of the time (not on the UI) is being taken ?
2. How do I fasten this process of Gradient Boosting on Spark. If you see most of the tasks are what is happening inside ML Lib and Decision Trees. I have used 5 partitions - should I increase it more ? How much more ?
3. The data keeps on increasing and reaches 19GB from 37MB. Why exactly ? - is this a concern ?
4. After some time when I have finished my training and I try to write out the predictions (out of folds) - I get a Size exceeds INT Max_Value error. And the reason is - it seems too many lines are being written out ? is it per partition ?
5. I have to train the GBT for 300 number of rounds. I am struggling at 3-4 hours for a POC with 3 number of rounds. Is it at all possible to do a 300 rounds Gradient Boosting in Spark using MLLib ?

I am on scala 2.10.4 and mllib 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

For question 2:

GBT trains only one tree iteratively. If you wish to fasten the process, try using Random Forests. RF trains an ensemble of trees in parallel, which is way faster than GBT.

Comment: Yes - I understand that - but I have done it locally with GBT and the predictions are much better than RF with my training data. In fact nowadays GB is becoming almost the default algorithm for any ML problem - specially with the coming of XGBoost. I hope some one can help me out. Thanks for your reply